# Why does my getc() always return 30 when input is 0 in C?

Tags: c, file, io, getc

> ```
> int main(void){
>     char buffer[5] = {0};  
>     int i;
>     FILE *fp = fopen("haha.txt", "r");
>     if (fp == NULL) {
>     perror("Failed to open file \"mhaha\"");
>     return EXIT_FAILURE;
>     }
>     for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
>         int rc = getc(fp);
>         if (rc == EOF) {
>             fputs("An error occurred while reading the file.\n", stderr);
>             return EXIT_FAILURE;
>         }
>     buffer[i] = rc;
>     }
>     fclose(fp);
>     printf("The bytes read were... %x %x %x %x %x\n", buffer[0], buffer[1], buffer[2], buffer[3], buffer[4]);
>     return EXIT_SUCCESS;
> }
> ```

I put eight 0s in my haha.txt file, and when I run this code it always gives me :

> The bytes read were... 30 30 30 30 30

Can someone tell me why?

Comment: Because `0`'s ASCII code is `30` in hexadecimal.

Comment: Change `%x` to `%c` in `printf` call.

Answer (score 2):

because '0' == 0x30

The character '0' is the 0x30 (ascii).

Answer (score 0):

`'0'` that you have entered in your text file is interpreted as `char` and not as an `int`. Now, when you try to print that `char` in its `hex (%x)` value, the code just finds the equivalent of that `char` in `hex` and prints it.

So, your `'0' = 0x30`. You can also try giving 'A' in your text file and printing it as hex, you will be getting '41' because `'A' = 0x41`.
For your reference, the [AsciiTable](http://www.asciitable.com/).

If you want to print out exactly what you have typed in your text file, then simply change your `printf("The bytes read were... %x %x %x %x %x\n", buffer[0], buffer[1], buffer[2], buffer[3], buffer[4]);`

To

```
printf("The bytes read were... %c %c %c %c %c\n", buffer[0], buffer[1], buffer[2], buffer[3], buffer[4]); 
/* %c will tell the compiler to print the chars as char and not as hex values. */
```

You might want to read [Format Specifiers](http://www.codingunit.com/printf-format-specifiers-format-conversions-and-formatted-output) and [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75w45ekt.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

In your `printf` you use `%x` and this print in `hex`. The `char '0'` is equal to `48 in decimal` so `0x30 in hex`.

To print `0 in char` you need to use `printf` with `%c`